# Showing a conditional form field on load, and when preselected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery code for showing/hiding a conditional form field (contained within `tr#other-employer`).  This works fine, once the page is loaded and options are changed.

I would like make it so that the conditinal field shows when the page is loaded and the option selected in the drop-down list with `#employer` is pre-selected (this is done with PHP).

I have tried removing `$('tr#other-employer').hide();` , but then this showed the conditional field on load regardless if the drop-down field is other or not.

A simple sample page is here: http://brenda.upreach.org.uk/beta/form.php

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('tr#other-employer').hide();
    $('#employer').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "Other") {
            $('tr#other-employer').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('tr#other-employer').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can add an if condition like below to check the status of the select box and do the needful.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  $('tr#other-employer').hide();    



    /*********************************/

      if($("select#employer").val() == "Other")
      {          $('tr#other-employer').fadeIn();  }  

    /*********************************/

$('#employer').change(function () {
if ($(this).val() == "Other") {
$('tr#other-employer').fadeIn();
} else {
$('tr#other-employer').hide();
}
});
});
```

> you can also set the select box default option from jquery using
>
> $("select#employer").val("Other");

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally understand the question, but if you're looking for the same functionality this code provides, but without the action being a requirement, then just remove the `.change()` function, and swap out the `this` for the id:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('tr#other-employer').hide();
    if ($('#employer').val() == "Other") {
       $('#other-employer').fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Edit:

The above should work, given the following HTML (I've removed the table code from both to simplify the explanation):

```
<form>
    <select id="#employer">
        <option value="Foo">Foo</option>
        <option value="Other" selected="selected">Other</option>
    </select>
    <select id="#other-employer">
        <option value="Foo">Bar</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Given the above code the #other-employer dropdown will display only if the 'Other' option is  preselected on load.

Comment: Thanks @Nathan The code doesn't quote seem to work though... I made a  quick sample page here with the old code.: http://brenda.upreach.org.uk/beta/form.php  I'm trying to make it display the conditional field if other is preselected

Comment: So what you're trying to achieve is:

If one field is preselected, display another field?

Comment: The answer you've accepted does the same thing as mine, btw. Thanks anyway :/ The only difference is I removed the 'change' condition which I felt was implied. The above code should have worked regardless, especially as the accepted answer is has the exact same change.